# How to integrate tesseract OCR with Cordova/Phonegap app

Tags: javascript, java, cordova, ocr, tesseract

Im trying use tesseract OCR with my app and by instructions posted here

http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2015/05/15/create-an-ocr-android-app-with-cordova-and-tesseract

several times I followed the instructions but with no success.When im inspecting code with Google Chrome Dev console thru the WebVieW it give me

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }**

in file **tesseractPlugin.js:11**

thats located somewhere in

**file:///android_asset/www/plugins/com.tesseract.phonegap/tesseractPlugin/tesseractPlugin.js**

and

**Uncaught Error: Module com.tesseract.phonegap.tesseractPlugin.TesseractPlugin does not exist.**

in **cordova.js:1431**

witch i think means the cordova cant find the plugin but i dont know why.I think it's something with the version of Cordova and its access to plugins

its frustrating because there are no other options on the web and i dont know how to write my own cordova plugin.

I would also like to add that I created the project exactly as instructed to avoid the mistakes and over I have found that it is not possible to download the plugin by git from

https://github.com/engzhaowei/Tesseract-phonegap-android-example/tree/master/plugins/com.tesseract.phonegap.tesseractPlugin

so i downloaded full package and fetch plugin from

**C:\xxx\plugins\com.tesseract.phonegap.tesseractPlugin**

Comment: i also tried to install it via cordova plugin add com.tesseract.phonegap.tesseractPlugin but it reports a timeout error connection. And the owner of that page seems to not respond... :(

Answer (score 2):

There is tessaract js http://tesseract.projectnaptha.com/
which is a javascript library and you can use it and will work for phonegap its very easy to implement.
Just reference the cdn script in the header and call the code snippet it should work. Be warned actress is slow.

```
 <script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/naptha/tesseract.js/1.0.10/dist/tesseract.js'></script>

 var myimage = document.getElementById("largeImage").src;

      Tesseract.recognize(myimage)
    .then(function(result){
       // console.log(result);
document.getElementById("textarea1").value = result.text; // assign results to a textbox
```

Comment: Well the response time is very slow when using the JS lib :(